# How to use databases that are using for java web application in django framework?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I have databases that are used another web application, i want to use same databases for django application. I have the idea i can call the database by using db cursor but i want to use database as usual like django way like tablename.object.all(). Is there any breakthrough?

Comment: Why should a database that's "developed in java" be any different from any other database that you use in Django?

Comment: Sorry type mistake. database are using in java.

Comment: Be careful to use a semaphore system or you will have problems

Comment: no difference create  your models but if you have data in this db juste use migration tools like South http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part1.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
python manage.py inspectdb
```

outputs general models from your db that u defined it in settings file.

```
python manage.py inspectdb > ./your_app/models.py
```

creates models.py file from the output in *nix systems.

But be ready for problems...

Comment: thanks.i got tables into my app models.py. i have to check it with using in my app.

Comment: you may want to make sure your models `Meta` has `managed=False` and the right `db_table` too. Oh and yes: you may also need to install the core django tables using `manage.py syncdb`, cf https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/legacy-databases/

Comment: i have successfully imported my legacy db into django models. But i am facing the issue in that, in my legacy db tables i have filed name called "id". for that while running the python manage.py sqlcustom [appname] i am getting error " "id": You can't use "id" as a field name, because each model automatically gets an "id" field if none of the fields have primary_key=True. You need to either remove/rename your "id" field or add primary_key=True to a field." is there any breakthrough for problem?

Comment: Why don't u simply remove id field from your converted models' definations?